# ¿Cómo dividir sintácticamente esta frase?

Tags: sintaxis, categorías-gramaticales

Estoy haciendo unos análisis sintácticos, y me topé con esta frase:

> Si le contaba a Carmen la verdad, que no tenía ni la menor intención
>   no sólo de divorciarse sino de separarse, Carmen se evaporaría,
>   desaparecería

He llegado a esto:

[image: Árbol sintáctico]
Pero no estoy seguro de la legitimidad de este árbol.

Si me pudieran ayudar de alguna manera, estaría muy agradecido.

Saludos.

Comment: Ese árbol es de otra oración distinta, ¿no? ¿Por qué oración estás preguntado, "Cada vez que se veían, que poco a poco era cada vez más a menudo, Carmen le preguntaba cómo iba el divorcio" o "Tenía la sensación de que si le contaba a Carmen la verdad, que no tenía ni la menor intención no sólo de divorciarse sino de separarse, Carmen se evaporaría, desaparecería, y la sola idea le ponía enfermo"?

Comment: si, tiene razón, lo corije.

Answer (score 3):

Yo analizaría "que no tenía ni la menor intención no sólo de divorciarse sino de separarse" como una aposición del núcleo del objeto directo, "la verdad".

Prueba de esto es que la misma oración se puede expresar así:

- Si le contaba a Carmen la verdad **de** que no tenía ni la menor intención no sólo de divorciarse sino de separarse, Carmen se evaporaría, desaparecería.
- Si le contaba a Carmen la verdad (que no tenía ni la menor intención no sólo de divorciarse sino de separarse), Carmen se evaporaría, desaparecería.

Comment: Modifiqué el post, quierías hablar de algo así ?

Comment: No. "la verdad, que no tenía ni la menor intención no sólo de divorciarse sino de separarse" es objeto directo (OD) dentro de la condicional. Dentro del OD, "verdad" es núcleo y "que no tenía ni la menor intención no sólo de divorciarse sino de separarse" es una proposición sustantiva en aposición a "verdad".

Comment: Che, una pregunta. Al margen de que sea muy común verlo, ¿es correcto usar el modo indicativo pretérito para introducir una situación irreal (si le  **contaba**)? ¿Qué dirías al respecto?

Comment: @tac Sugiero que veas esta pregunta relacionada: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35304/por-qu%C3%A9-fue-usado-el-pret%C3%A9rito-imperfecto-en-la-cl%C3%A1usula-principal-de-la-oraci%C3%B3n