# Por qué fue usado el pretérito imperfecto en la cláusula principal de la oración condicional

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, condicional

Encontré dos oraciones.

De la película "El Secreto de sus Ojos" (Argentina):

*"Si me hubiesen pedido una cita los **esperaba** con un café "*

De la serie de Netflix "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

"*Si no tuviera la cadera hecha una fosfatina, te **daba** un mes de vacaciones.*"

¿Por qué fue usado el pretérito imperfecto el la parte subordinada de las oracíones? No encontré la respuesta en
http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Condicional%20hipot%C3%A9tico.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El pretérito imperfecto del indicativo puede usarse coloquialmente tanto en la prótasis (cláusula condicional) como en la apódosis (cláusula principal) de las oraciones condicionales para referirse a situaciones contrafácticas en el pasado:

- Si me **pedían** una cita los **esperaba** con un café. (= Si me hubieran pedido..., los habría esperado ...)

En la oración:

- Si no tuviera la cadera hecha una fosfatina, te **daba** un mes de vacaciones.

sólo es posible el pretérito imperfecto del indicativo en la apódosis porque la prótasis se refiere al presente:

- Si no tuviera la cadera hecha una fosfatina (ahora), te **habría dado** un mes de vacaciones.

Si la condición se refiriera al pasado, se podría usar coloquialmente el pretérito imperfecto del indicativo en ambas partes de la oración:

- Si no **tenía** la cadera hecha una fosfatina (en ese momento), te **daba** un mes de vacaciones. (= Si no hubiera tenido ..., te habría dado ...)

Pregunta relacionada: [Pregunta sobre tiempo y modo verbal en las oraciones condicionales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21349/pregunta-sobre-tiempo-y-modo-verbal-en-las-oraciones-condicionales)